# PHP Soap with Crowd wsdl

Tags: php, soap

I am trying to write a code for sso login with crowd in my custom php application. I trying to to do that with SOAP. I am in a early stage now and was going through the documentation of how to connect php soap with wsdl. But i seem to be stuck very deep as i dont know what should be done next.

```
<?php
 class test {
        function authenticateApplication()
        {
            $client = new SoapClient("http://localhost:8095/crowd/services/SecurityServer?wsdl");
            $param = array('in0' => array('credential' => 'password','name' => 'app'));
            $resp=$client->authenticateApplication($param);
            $token = $resp->out->token;
            print_r($resp);
        }
    }
     $t= new test;
     $t->authenticateApplication();
```

I Dont know whats wrong with this code. I have referred it online and it seems to be correct but when i am tring to run this program i am getting this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Client] The validated object is null in /var/www/html/badebade/soaptest.php:7 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/badebade/soaptest.php(7): SoapClient->__call('authenticateApp...', Array) #1 /var/www/html/badebade/soaptest.php(7): SoapClient->authenticateApplication(Array) #2 /var/www/html/badebade/soaptest.php(13): test->authenticateApplication() #3 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/badebade/soaptest.php on line 7
```

A little help will be much appreciated as this program authenticates the application in crowd wsdl and returns the token. Can someone help me to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Find($request) {
try {
    $soapClient = new SoapClient('wsdl.wsdl', array('trace' => 1));
    $results = $soapClient->authenticateApplication($request);
    return $results;
}
catch(SoapFault $ex) {
    print $ex->getMessage();
    echo '<HR>';
    print $ex->getTraceAsString();
    echo '<HR>';
    echo $ex->getLine();

}
```

}

$results = Find($params);

Comment: The validated object is null
#0 /var/www/html/badebade/soaptest.php(17): SoapClient->__call('authenticateApp...', Array) #1 /var/www/html/badebade/soaptest.php(17): SoapClient->authenticateApplication(Array) #2 /var/www/html/badebade/soaptest.php(31): Find(Array) #3 {main}
17

Comment: Thankyou for the reply the above was the error received